# An error occurred (RequestEntityTooLargeException) when calling the UpdateFunctionCode operation

Tags: aws-lambda

When I deploy lambda function using the command below, the error is occured.

```
aws lambda update-function-code --function-name example --zip-file fileb://lambda.zip
```

```
An error occurred (RequestEntityTooLargeException) when calling the UpdateFunctionCode operation
```

As far as I looked through, my zip size can not be reduced any more.
How can I avoid this or are there any alternative way to deploy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although layers are a good way to solve this, you can also upload your `.zip` file to S3 and update your function to the extent of:

```
aws lambda update-function-code --function-name LAMBDA_NAME --region REGION_NAME --s3-bucket BUCKET_NAME --s3-key S3_KEY/TO/PACKAGE.zip
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a limit to direct upload of 50MB:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-limits.html

You can use a LambdaLayer as a workaround to this problem:

- https://lumigo.io/blog/lambda-layers-when-to-use-it/
- https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-lambda-layers-to-simplify-your-development-process/

With layers, you got **250MB** Limit

A disclosure - I'm a developer in Lumigo, we have just a blogpost on this thread, shared also an official AWS post.